# Columnwise Pearson Correlation using Numpy Python

Tags: python, numpy, pearson-correlation

I am trying to calculate the columnwise Pearson correlation using 2 2D arrays each with size 27495x92. I wish to have the resulting correlation matrix with size 92x92. I did try one way as shown below but the values are greater than 1. I was wondering if this is a normalisation issue and I would be grateful if anyone could suggest a simpler way to do same with the numpy function. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
trans_rsfMRI_corr_2d = (trans_rsfMRI_corr_2d - trans_rsfMRI_corr_2d.mean(axis = 0)) / trans_rsfMRI_corr_2d.std(axis = 0)
trans_mvfMRI_corr_2d = (trans_mvfMRI_corr_2d - trans_mvfMRI_corr_2d.mean(axis = 0)) / trans_mvfMRI_corr_2d.std(axis = 0)
rs_mv_corr = np.dot(trans_rsfMRI_corr_2d.T, trans_mvfMRI_corr_2d) / trans_rsfMRI_corr_2d.shape[0]`
```

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel: [`np.corrcoef`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html?highlight=corrcoef#numpy.corrcoef) should do it.

Comment: Unfortunately, it gives me a matrix of 184x184.